# Apache <Directory /var/www/*> vs. <Directory /var/www/>

Tags: apache-2.2

What is the difference between

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options All -Indexes
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
Options All -Indexes
</Directory>
```

?

The first **does not** work, the second **does** work, on my server. And there doesn't appear to be any other configuration files overriding the setting. I thought they meant the same thing.

---

**Edit:** It turns out there was another configuration file affecting the server that was overriding this one, so that was causing the unexpected result. I guess having * superseded the other configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

`/var/www/` includes all files in the directory. `/var/www/*` does not include hidden files. I see a `.htaccess` file in your future.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  I just checked and the first one works for me.  Do you have any files in the directory?  When you are changing directory are you using the following command?

```
cd /var/www
```

If you are typing an extra "/" at the end  such as:

```
cd /var/www/
```

then it may be looking for another directory.

Comment: It turns out there was another configuration file affecting the server that was overriding this one, so that was causing the unexpected result. I guess having * superseded the other configuration file.

Comment: @mattloaf1 - could you please say which file was that? thank you